# Finding hypervolume lying between Gaussian function and x-y-z plane over $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, volume

Define the 3-variable Gaussian function by $G(x,y,z) = e^{-(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2})}$.     Find the hypervolume lying between this surface and the x-y-z hyperplane, over the entire domain of $\mathbb{R}^3$; i.e., the volume in $\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by :
$$ w \in [0,G(x,y,z)], \quad x\in -(\infty,+\infty), y\in -(\infty,+\infty), z\in -(\infty,+\infty) . $$
I guess we have to compute an integral but I might be wrong and if it's that case I have a trouble setting up the integral and visualize it (if that's possible).

Comment: Did you intend to write $G$ instead of $N$? If yes: you have to calculate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} G(x,y,z) dx dy dz$. If not, I don't know.

Comment: @Thomas  sorry.  edited.

Comment: If we integrate over $x,y,z$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, how does that relate to "between this surface and the x-y-z plane"?

Comment: To get some idea what you are doing just assume for a second that you have a function of only two variables (leave out $z$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{t^2}}\, dx$. Using the fact that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx = \sqrt{\pi}$, we have $F(t) = t\sqrt{\pi}$, by the $u$-substitution $u = \frac{x}{t}$.

Hence, the hypervolume is $$\int_{\Bbb R^3} \int_0^{G(x,y,z)} 1\, dw\, dV = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} + \frac{z^2}{c^2}\right)}\, dz\, dy\, dx = F(a)F(b)F(c) = abc\,\pi^{3/2}.$$

Comment: Thanks, Kobe.  There is another follow-up question:  how can the result (the answer we got) be used to define a normalized surface, for which the integrated volume over all space is unity ?

Comment: @Paul555 define your (new) surface by $$w = \frac{G(x,y,z)}{abc\,\pi^{3/2}}$$